# Equivalent of readystatechange after changing page content using javascript

Tags: javascript, readystate

I am modifying dynamically a part of page (which is loaded only once), using javascript.
I am looking for an equivalent of `readystatechange` event that will be triggered when all images, fonts, ... are loaded after the partial page change.

How can I achieve that?

Note: Reloading the full page is not an option for performances reasons

I am using vanilla JS:

```
containerElement.innerHTML = htmlString;
```

Comment: Please show us the code you're using to modify the page. The approach is different in React, Angular, etc., and will likely be very different for a custom-coded system. We can't tell you how to determine when everything is loaded unless we know the code you're using to load it all.

Comment: I am using vanilla javascript and simply replace the `innerHTML `

Comment: So you're making an AJAX call with XMLHttpRequest, and when you get a response, that response is just HTML and you're setting the containerElement's innerHTML to that response without any modification or processing?

Comment: It is inside an application. The page is loaded into a web view and The application invoke javascript to change innerHTML of container DIV

Comment: Well, DIVs don't have a direct way to detect when their contents have loaded, so without a framework, you'll have to basically build your own version of a load event. You can detect when images, videos, etc. load but not things that come from stylesheets, or other non-external DOM elements. I'll post an answer that I think might work, though I would highly recommend using a framework like Angular or React for single-page applications like this: it will make your life much, much easier :)

Comment: Im interested about alternatives. How would you do?

Comment: Personally? I would use React and Webpack :D It provides support for lazy-loading components and assets and has a built-in component (called a "Suspense") that handles detecting when these lazy-loaded assets have finished loading or not. If you're interested, I'd suggest looking into React Hooks with lazy loading and code splitting :) (Oh, and if you do look into it, I also suggest using hook-router for routing instead of React Router; I just find it easier and more elegant than React Router when using React Hooks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do, if you're doing everything manually with vanilla JS, is detect when child elements that support the load event (images, videos, etc.) all finish loading. It's not a perfect representation of the DIV being loaded, but maybe it'll be close enough for your purposes.

So just after you set the innerHTML of your DIV, call a function that does something like this:

```
function onDivLoaded(div, callback) {
    const loadable_types = ['img', 'video', 'frame', 'frameset', 'iframe', 'link', 'script'];
    const total = {};
    const loaded = {};

    function tryCallback(type) {
        ++loaded[type];
        const hasMore = loadable_types.some(type => loaded[type] < total[type]);
        if (!hasMore) { callback(div); }
    }

    loadable_types.forEach(type => {
        const els = div.getElementsByTagName(type);
        total[type] = els.length;
        loaded[type] = 0;
        els.forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener('load', () => tryCallback(type));
            element.addEventListener('error', () => tryCallback(type));
        });
    });
}
```

So basically, after setting the innerHTML, you'd call onDivLoaded and pass it the container DIV and the callback to run when it's loaded. This will then attach load and error handlers to every DOM element inside the DIv that supports those events, and whenever one fires, it'll track how many are loaded out of how many total. When 100% of the loadable elements are loaded, it'll fire the callback.

Comment: Thanks! How can I do for background images defined as inline CSS?

Comment: You can't. Inline style elements don't support checking when they've loaded or when their URL assets have loaded.